# SAPUI5 Custom control does not render updated data at runtime

Tags: sapui5

I've created a custom control where I have 5 properties and render a graph based on them like so:

```
renderer : function(manager, myControl) {
    manager.write("<div>");
    manager.write("Some html stuff");
    manager.write("</div>");
}
```

here everything works fine and render the graph with my pre selected model data. The problem comes when I try to change some of the proparties at runtime. In the method `rerender` the code is triggered when some of the properties are changed but the rendering is not applied. The method itself is identical, just the manager is instanciated.

```
rerender : function() {
    console.log("trigger");
    var manager = new sap.ui.core.RenderManager();
    manager.write("<div>");
    manager.write("Some html stuff");
    manager.write("</div>");
}
```

I also tried to create a global object `manager` and make both `managers` in above to be the same thing. The result was the same...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom UI5 control does not update bound value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68899274/custom-ui5-control-does-not-update-bound-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `oRm.writeControlData(oControl);` to the `renderer`

In your case

```
renderer : function(manager, myControl) {
    manager.write("<div");
    manager.writeControlData(myControl);
    manager.write(">");
    manager.write("Some html stuff");
    manager.write("</div>");
}
```

Go through [API reference: `sap/ui/core/RenderManager`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.RenderManager)